# Multiple variables with v-bind Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to pass multiple variables in the following code:

```
<div v-bind:onloadstart='functionOFF = true; editOFF = true'></div>
```

but I get the following error:

> [Vue warn]: Failed to generate render function: SyntaxError:
>   Unexpected token ; in

I tried replacing the `;` with a `,` but the I get:

> [Vue warn]: Failed to generate render function: SyntaxError: Invalid
>   shorthand property initializer in

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: move those into metrod?

Comment: @dfsq - yeah I though about that, just wanted to see if there's a way to doing it directly

Comment: try to do it with `&` or `&&` operator maybe

Comment: @JulienMetral - Yeah I tried with both and I get a compiling error

Comment: To listen to a method, you should use v-on:onloadstart='functionOFF = true; editOFF = true'

Comment: why don't you just create a method, and then call a method within your event handler? It might be more elegant?

Answer (score 5):

also, you can use from below way:

```
<input v-bind:value="[item.id, item.name]">
```

Comment: you are a legend! Ty for posting this

Answer (score 1):

spreading them in to object and using them in bind if object else add them like shown..

```
<MyComponent v-bind="{...$attrs, featAProps, featBProps}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [document](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind), v-bind should be an value or an object.

> **v-bind**
>
> Expects: any (with argument) | Object (without argument)
>
> Argument: attrOrProp (optional)

You should use v-on to listen to event (in this case onloadstart). v-on can use with Inline Statement

> **v-on**
>
> Expects: Function | Inline Statement | Object
>
> Argument: event

```
<div v-on:onloadstart='functionOFF = true; editOFF = true'></div>
```

Comment: I've tried it and it does render the page but now the value of the variables aren't changed :s

Comment: I think onloadstart might not be supported by major browser (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onloadstart). You should put `functionOFF = true; editOFF = true` in `created` hook of Vue component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use anonymous function if you don't want to declare a method:

```
<div v-bind:onloadstart='()=>{functionOFF = true; editOFF = true;}'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Vue 3, I wasn't having much luck with the array syntax

```js
<MyComponent v-bind="[$attr, propA]">
```

but I found [this comment](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/4105#issuecomment-981330696) in Vue's github repo.

This led me to try

```js
<MyComponent v-bind="($attrs, props)" :anotherProp="anotherProp">
```

which ended up working for me.