# is there a way to pass muttiple values which are not in side a component(dom)?

Tags: vue.js

I am very new to Vue,
i tried to simulate this in bellow link.

https://jsfiddle.net/kyncgL7w/9/

I have this simple html select tag. Where I am showing values from `object(banks)`. 
now I have used `v-on:change` so when ever user will select any values, i want to get values of

`> ledger_object_type_sub_id and ledger_object_type_sub_name`

Now, I can get the `ledger_object_type_sub_id` from `v-bind` or `v-model`, 
but how do i pass the value of `ledger_object_type_sub_name` into a function.

i.e `get_existing_bank_id(bank_name_id, **bank_name**)` so that i can use that value can be use later on?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to find in your `banks` array the `ledger_object_type_sub_id` who is equal to your `bank_name_id`.

```js
get_existing_bank_id: function(bank_name_id) {
  console.log(this.banks.find(bank => bank.ledger_object_type_sub_id === bank_name_id).ledger_object_type_sub_name);
}
```

Here is your fiddle update with the working solution : https://jsfiddle.net/sjh038w9/

Answer (score 1):

Just bind object value on your option tag

```
<option v-bind:value="bank">..</option>
```

Comment: @Andrien Leloir, 
There is already one bind value, can i two v-bind:value for the same compnent ?

Comment: Yes you can with array or object : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51302456/multiple-variables-with-v-bind-vue-js